# How to segue based on the PFRole of the current user

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I have an app where there are 2 roles, "admin" and "employee". At sign up I have the segue set up into the sign up button and it automatically performs the right segue to the employee or admin view controllers. But after the user is created and logged out and try to log back in how can I set up a conditional if else statement that queries the role of the current user and performs the correct segue accordingly. thanks in advance. here is the code i have on the initial view controller/Login Screen.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

//need to query current users role...and then if else, and segue to either Admin Home or Employee Home



     var roleQueryClass = PFQuery(className: "_Role")
     var roleQuery = PFRole.query()
     roleQuery?.whereKey("name", equalTo: "Admin")
     roleQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

  if let role = objects {

    for object in role {

      if let role = object as? PFRole {



        if PFRole() == PFUser.currentUser() {

          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHomeFromSignUp", sender: self)

        } else {

          self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toEmployeeHome", sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of signup save the role in NSUserDefaults, and at the time of login , check the value in NSUserDefaults , and segue accordingly.

Comment: I not to familiar with the NSUserDefaults. Ill have to brush up on it. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Hey Anita, Im trying to what you said...maybe you can help me finish....I have the following code in the userDidSignupInBackGroundWithBlock trying to set the NSUserDefault.... and then on my Login Screen I'm trying to get the Key that i set....does this look right to you? I can't get it to segue to the right one.          let defaultName = "Admin"                                                             let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
          defaults.setObject("Role", forKey:defaultName)
          defaults.synchronize()

Comment: here is the code in on my login Viewcontroller under ViewDidAppear, trying to find the key and segue accordingly.    if (PFUser.currentUser() != nil) {
  
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
     if let name = defaults.stringForKey("Admin") {
    
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toHomeFromLogin", sender: self)
      
    }else {
      
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toEmployeeHome", sender: self)
    }
    }

Comment: not exactly sure where i can set this....my app will crash when i have it in the sign up method.... can you not set a PFUser as an object?                                  let user = PFUser.currentUser()
          let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
          defaults.setObject(user, forKey:"Admin")
          defaults.synchronize()

Comment: set the NSuserDefaults in app delegate,  set when updated in your loginview controller  and synchronze.

Comment: to set value    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("Coding Explorer", forKey: "userNameKey") then to access that value let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let name = defaults.stringForKey("userNameKey")
{
    println(name)
}